# Is there a way to ask someone if they've gained knowledge from something new they experienced?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am what you'd call a neophiliac and have many friends who enjoy doing/seeing/experiencing new things, be it through travel or interpersonal encounters. 
We always seem to struggle for a better way to just ask "Did something new happen to you, did you learn something new about another culture, did you discover new types of behavior or customs?", etc.
Does anyone know a phrase for it or a word we could at least make up a question from?

Comment: *Did you [expand your horizons?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22expand+your+horizons%22)

Comment: The simple "What have you learned?" seems serviceable. Add a comma after "what" to offer a challenge.

Comment: Did it give you a new perspective ? Or did it allow you see things differently ? Or Did it open your eyes? Was it an eye opener?

Comment: "So what did you learn from that?"

Comment: Steep learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

"So, you've been traveling in Continent XX.  Did you reach any ***[enlightenment](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enlighten)***?"

Or:

"Anything enlightening in your recent travels?"

> Enlighten: Give (someone) greater knowledge and understanding about a subject or situation

*(Oxford)*

Comment: Enlightenment seems awfully momentous.  "No, I didn't reach enlightenment, but I learned scuba diving, and I found out I like plantains"

Comment: @JohnFeltz - That's the *other* meaning of the word.  Actually, that's why I provided an alternative phrasing, using just the verb -- less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You might try "Did you *[broaden your horizons](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/broaden_one's_horizons)* on that trip?"

> Broaden one's horizons: Expand one's range of interests, activities,
>   and knowledge.

*(Oxford)*

As @FumbleFingers mentions in the comments, "did you expand *[your horizons](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/expand+horizons)* on that trip?" isn't a bad option either.

> Expand one's horizons: to experience and learn new things.

*(TFD)*

Here's one last one: "did you *broaden your worldview* on that trip?" (I wasn't able to find any source in a dictionary for that, but I've heard it thrown quite often in common speech, so here are [some](https://www.bustle.com/articles/151250-7-books-that-will-help-you-expand-your-worldview) examples of news [articles](http://www.npr.org/2014/08/28/344036651/want-to-widen-your-worldview-a-random-roomie-helps) with that phrase in the title.